# AutoFocusComplete event windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, microsoft-tag

So I am trying to develop a Windows Phone mobile application that utilizes Microsoft TAG technology.

I'm starting from the base of using the TagSdkSample project provided with the Microsoft TAG SDK.

I cannot get the program to spit anything out when debugging (I am debugging on my Windows 8 phone) and I'm assuming it has to do with the auto focus capabilities (its recognizes the TAG but gets really blurry right before the picture is snapped).  In the code there is a comment mentioning how this is a bad way for autofocus to work:

```
    private void GetImageAndDecode()
    {
        // This is not a good way to auto focus. It is better to have an AutoFocusCompleted event
        // handler to start capturing after focus is made. This sample code is not for
        // full application demonstration.
        camera.Focus();
        camera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(previewPixels);
        imageToDecode = new ImageToDecode(previewPixels, ImageFormat.ARGB32, previewWidth, previewHeight);
        TagContext.Current.ScanFromFrame(imageToDecode);
    }
```

How would I implement that event handler within this code?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the `PhotoCamera` object initialization:

```
camera.AutoFocusCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(Camera_AutoFocusCompleted);
```

Then add the following method:

```
void cam_AutoFocusCompleted(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Do what you want here
}
```